# JSP retaining values while navigating multiple windows

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, httpsession

[image]

Assumption: MVC framework is being used

In the web application ,there is parent(main screen) where the values are displayed through the request scope and an event on parent window popups the child window.  Then if user does update some value in child screen , the parent window has to be updated with new value [and also retaining the parent windows variable values].

Is there **design pattern** to approach this kind ? we need to store both the forms in HttpSession?

Comment: Avoid the session by all means, especially to store values that don't have a whole session lifetime. You don't need a design pattern. You need to call a JavaScript callback function of the parent window from the child window.

Comment: If parent windows has lot of values like tables, values, do we need to load everything again with the value that is being passed through Javascript?

Comment: Not necessarily: you can pass everything in the callback function. But reloading the data in the parent window is sometimes the easiest and cleanest way. Don't optimize prematurely.

Comment: I am very new to JQuery.If I can make use of JQuery and Ajax on this scenario, can we prevent reloading. request scope values in the parent window will be retained?